# Wordpress permalink slug automatically changing and creating a new page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've never seen this happen before. I have a page and we can call it overview.
website.com/overview

This page has been called overview for 5 years and the slug has always been /overview

Then one day when I go to edit the page I navigate to website.com/overview and click the edit page button. I then see that the permalink slug has changed to /overview-2 and it won't let me change it back. Weird.

So I save it as /overview-2 and all related child pages and images switch to being associated to /overview-2.

Ok, this is the weirdest part. I then navigate to the original page website.com/overview and that page resolves to a new page that was created (new post ID) at the same time stamp as I saved the /overview-2 page.

I was able to recreate this issue when I noticed another page on the website do the same thing. We'll call it /another. This time instead on saving the page as /another-2 I went into the permalink settings and changed them back to default then back to post name. I navigate back to /another and it now has a new post id and the original page and all child pages and images are now associated with /another-2.

All plugs are up to date and core is running the newest 4.9.4 version of wordpress.

Anyone know what gives?

Comment: there is too few info for detecting which may be the main reason for your problem. its some query with db, which changed/added new post. the prbolem may be with theme/plugins or even you may changed something. what is your goal now? find, where is the bug? or fix the part with child pages, images and etc. ?

Comment: look this topic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44634/strange-permalink-issue-cant-rename-company-2-to-company and also i think this can help https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-old-slugspermalinks/